# jTable and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Help create a Table model for the next object.
Suppose there is a class

```
public class Class1 implements Serializable {

    private Long id = null;
    private String name = null;
    private Set <Class2> transaction = new HashSet <Class2> ();

    get and set ...
}

public class Class2 implements Serializable {

    private Long class1Id = null;
    private String field1 = null;
    private Class1 class1 = null;

    get and set ...
}
```

A one-to-many.
The table display id, name, field1. 1, "John", asd; 1, "John", 2; .... Something like this. Give examples of what can be anything?

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? How is Hibernate relevant to this question?

Comment: The number of objects in the class, I say 10, have each may be any number of others. How to bring to the table, all these lines? Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `Class1WithTransaction` containing an instance of Class1, and an instance of Class2.
Iterate over the Class1 instances, and then over each of its transactions, and populate a `List<Class1WithTransaction>`:

```
List<Class1WithTransaction> list = new ArrayList<Class1WithTransaction>();
for (Class1 c1 : theObjects) {
    if (c1.getTransactions().isEmpty()) {
        list.add(new Class1WithTransaction(c1, null));
    }
    else {
        for (Class2 transaction : c1.getTransactions()) {
            list.add(new Class1WithTransaction(c1, transaction))
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have this list, you just have to create a table model around it. Each row of the table is an instance of `Class1WithTransaction`.